# edition$ in Oracle 11g

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

While checking v$sql in my database, I came across this query.

```
select p_obj#, flags, code, audit$ from edition$ where obj#=:1
```

Can anybody please explain what is this select statement for ?
I think the query is executed while gathering schema statistics by my application. But I cannot understand it.

Answer (score 4):

Oracle actually stores meta data information on base tables(usually followed by `$` sign on its name).
Its a base table for edition objects. `DBA_EDITIONS` is the view created for this base table.

> An edition makes it possible to have two or more versions of the same editionable objects in the database.

```
SQL> select obj# from edition$;

      OBJ#
----------
       133

SQL> select object_type, object_name from all_objects where object_id=133;

OBJECT_TYPE        OBJECT_NAME
----------------   -------------------
EDITION            ORA$BASE
```